# How to incorporate Cocoon links into buttons

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, haml, cocoon-gem

In a rails project I am using the [cocoon gem](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) to create a nested form. In the [provided example](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon#standard-rails-forms), the method `link_to_remove_association` is used, generating a link which deletes the current nested form when clicked.

This works fine as a link, but I wish to have the same functionality in a [nested bootstrap button](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons). Is this possible?

The best I have so far (which only inserts a link within the button):

```
%span.input-group-btn
    %button.btn.btn-default.btn-lg{type: 'button'}
      = link_to_remove_association "X", f, type:'button'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I used to accomplish this.

```
<%= link_to_remove_association button_tag('x', type: "button", class: "close"), f %>
```

Comment: Thanks, this isn't perfect but better than anything I could come up with.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of nesting a `button`, you can just apply the button-classes to style the link directly:

```
%span.input-group-btn
  = link_to_remove_association "X", f, class: 'btn btn-default btn-lg'
```